# Django form data into multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, html, django

In my HTML form i have multiple form fields:

```
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label for="label1">Label1</label>
                                          <input type="text" value="Card Number", name="card_number" class="form-control" id="label1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label for="placeholder1">Placeholder</label>
                                          <input type="text" value="Enter Card Number" name="card_number_placeholder" class="form-control" id="placeholder1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                      <label for="label2">Label2</label>
                                      <input type="text" value="Expiration" name="expiration" class="form-control" id="label2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                      <label for="placeholder2">Placeholder</label>
                                      <input type="text" value="MM/YY" name="expiration_placeholder" class="form-control" id="placeholder2">
                                    </div>
                               </div>
```

In my Django View when i convert the form data into dictionary using

```
data = request.POST.dict()
```

i get all the form field values as one single dictionary:

```
{'expiration_placeholder': ['MM/YY'], 'card_number_placeholder': ['Enter Card Number'], 'expiration': ['Expiration'], 'card_number': ['Card Number']}
```

How can i get these as multiple dictionaries on form submit as something below:

```
{{'expiration': ['Expiration'],'expiration_placeholder': ['MM/YY']}, {'card_number': ['Card Number'] 'card_number_placeholder': ['Enter Card Number']}}
```

If this structure is maintained it will be easier for me to parse and store as multiple rows in my database table

Comment: Can you please share your view?

Answer (score 0):

If all what you want is a dict of your request.POST data, you can use this:

```
data = {}
for p in request.POST:
    data[p] = request.POST[p]
```